# BindinContext is no longer bound after changing ContentTemplate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have build a Xamarin forms app and using Templates for my pages.

I've overwritten the OnAppearing with the following code.

```
public void OnAppearing(){
   ControlTemplate = Templates["mytemplate"]; 
}
```

I have a few ICommand in the viewmodel

If I comment out the ControlTemplate line the commands are bound properly, however if I change the template the ICommand's are not bound. I've also tested with a Text Property and it doesn't get bound either.

What could I be missing.

Comment: @What are your template and viewmodel? Please provide some code here.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT thanks, I have figured it out in the wee hours of the night, needed to ensure the template was set before applying the BindingContext.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your problem.